# How to retrieve java class from jna reference pointer

Tags: java, pointers, reference, jna

I am porting the [openvr sample](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) to [jogl](https://github.com/jovr/jogl-hello-vr), after we created the [binding](https://github.com/jovr/jopenvr) with jna.

Almost at the end (before rendering the controllers and the tracking base stations), I got stuck trying to retrieving the model class in java from a reference pointer in C++.

C++ code [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr):

```
while ( 1 )
{
    error = vr::VRRenderModels()->LoadRenderModel_Async( pchRenderModelName, &pModel );
    if ( error != vr::VRRenderModelError_Loading )
        break;

    ThreadSleep( 1 );
}
```

`LoadRenderModel_Async` [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2745):

```
/** Loads and returns a render model for use in the application. pchRenderModelName should be a render model name
* from the Prop_RenderModelName_String property or an absolute path name to a render model on disk. 
*
* The resulting render model is valid until VR_Shutdown() is called or until FreeRenderModel() is called. When the 
* application is finished with the render model it should call FreeRenderModel() to free the memory associated
* with the model.
*
* The method returns VRRenderModelError_Loading while the render model is still being loaded.
* The method returns VRRenderModelError_None once loaded successfully, otherwise will return an error. */
virtual EVRRenderModelError LoadRenderModel_Async( const char *pchRenderModelName, RenderModel_t **ppRenderModel ) = 0;
```

jna translated it as ([here](https://github.com/jovr/jopenvr/blob/master/jopenvr/src/vr/IVRRenderModels_FnTable.java#L103-L106)):

```
public interface LoadRenderModel_Async_callback extends Callback {

    int apply(Pointer pchRenderModelName, PointerByReference ppRenderModel);
};
```

On java I am trying to load the model in this way ([here](https://github.com/jovr/jogl-hello-vr/blob/master/jogl-hello-vr/src/helloVr/ModelsRender.java#L129-L145)):

```
int error;
PointerByReference modelPtrRef = new PointerByReference();

while (true) {

    Pointer stringPointer = new Memory(modelName.length());

    error = renderModels.LoadRenderModel_Async.apply(stringPointer, modelPtrRef);

    if (error != VR.EVRRenderModelError.VRRenderModelError_Loading) {
        break;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModelsRender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

RenderModel_t m = new RenderModel_t(modelPtrRef.getValue());
m.read();
```

But `m` is empty, that is `vertexData` is null and `vertexCount` is 0, on c++ I have valid values instead..

How shall I retrieve the java class from a reference pointer in c++?

Comment: JNA will do the string handling for you if you make `stringPointer` a `String`.

Comment: You should also define a `Pointer`-based constructor for `RenderModel_t`, which makes the call to `Structure.read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something a little simpler:

```
if (errorBuffer.get(0) != VR.EVRRenderModelError.VRRenderModelError_None) {
    return null;
}

int error;
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();

while (true) {

    error = renderModels.LoadRenderModel_Async.apply(modelName, pref);

    if (error != VR.EVRRenderModelError.VRRenderModelError_Loading) {
        break;
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModelsRender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
RenderModel_t model = new RenderModel_t(pref.getValue());


public class RenderModel_t {
    public RenderModel_t(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask, is it a good practise having the `read()` inside the pointer constructor? Because I'd like to do it for all my pointer constructors..

Comment: Yes, in most cases that's the best.  You'd only want to avoid it if you're making a base class that needs to be extended (in which case the constructor should probably be abstract), which is usually quite rare.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I needed to create a pointer `modelPtr`, then a pointer to a pointer `modelPtrPtr` and pass that to `LoadRenderModel_Async`.

At the end I instantiate a model class by passing the value of the pointer to a pointer and `read()` to retrieve the values from native to heap memory:

```
    RenderModel_t.ByReference modelPtr = new RenderModel_t.ByReference();

    if (errorBuffer.get(0) != VR.EVRRenderModelError.VRRenderModelError_None) {
        return null;
    }

    int error;
    PointerByReference modelPtrPtr = new PointerByReference(modelPtr.getPointer());

    while (true) {

        Pointer stringPointer = new Memory(modelName.length() + 1);
        stringPointer.setString(0, modelName);

        error = renderModels.LoadRenderModel_Async.apply(stringPointer, modelPtrPtr);

        if (error != VR.EVRRenderModelError.VRRenderModelError_Loading) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModelsRender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    RenderModel_t model = new RenderModel_t(modelPtrPtr.getValue());
    model.read();
```

Comment: The initial creation of a `RenderModel_t.ByReference` is superfluous.  Presumably the pointer value you initialize and pass by reference to `LoadRenderModel_Async.apply()` is overwritten.

Comment: You are right.. if you want to answer I'll accept it